# How to print values in a list where the indexes come from an int64 numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a series of values, such as:

```
values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

and a long list of indexes in an numpy array whose dtype is int64:

```
indexes = np.array([3, 0, 1], dtype=np.int64)
```

I'd like to print the items in the first list indicated by the indexes on this array, but if I do:

```
print(values[indexes])
```

then it fails with:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I'd like to see:

```
print(values[indexes])
>>> ['D', 'B', 'A']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a list comprehension or convert `values` to a numpy array.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without overloading the `__getitem__` attribute of a new list class

Comment: This is a basic Python task - list indexes have to be integers, not arrays or even lists.  The fact that `indexes` is a numpy array doesn't change how list indexing is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly try to access values like that, but you can do it using a list comprehension (or a for loop) to access each individual item in your `values` list, according to the `indexes` list.

```
import numpy as np

values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

indexes = np.array([3, 0, 1], dtype=np.int64)

print([values[i] for i in indexes])
```

Another way would be to make a function like this:

```
import numpy as np

def getValues(values, indexes):
    return [values[i] for i in indexes]

values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

indexes = np.array([3, 0, 1], dtype=np.int64)

print(getValues(values, indexes))
```